# Django admin how to show currency numbers in comma separated format

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my models I have this:

```py
class Example(Basemodel):
       price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and in my admin I have this:

```py
@admin.register(Example)
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('price',)
```

I want the price field to be shown in comma-separated format instead of the typical integer format and I want to do that on the backend side.
For example: 333222111 should be 333,222,111
Any can recommend me a solution?

[image]

Should be:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with a property instead, for example:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class Example(Basemodel):
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    @admin.display(description='price', ordering='price')
    def price_formatted(self):
        return f'{self.price:,}'
```

and use that property:

```
@admin.register(Example)
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('price_formatted',)
```

Comment: In line `@admin.display(description='price', ordering='price')` admin is unkown

Comment: @MehdiAria: you need to import it...

Comment: Thanks but this will work on the list of the objects, What if I want to see this format in the admin creation form of creating a new object? check the images on first post

Comment: While this works it's needlessly complicated. Using the `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` setting as suggested in another answer is much easier

Comment: @EvanBorgstrom: well there are two issues here: first of all, the setting will be applied to *anything*, so not only to that specific field, a second thing is that in the context of currencies, other things apply like two digits, and a currency symbol, so in that scenario, I guess using a custom field is more appropriate.

Comment: I think in the beginning I found settings indeed a good idea, but I think a few years ago, I started realizing this actually is some sort of *immutable* global state, which is indeed not that much of a problem compared to *mutable* global state, but in fact still has some (smaller) problems: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/351930/166310

Answer (score 4):

try [thousand seperator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/) in your settings.py

```
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```

alternatively you can use [intercoma](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) to convert integer to a string containing commas every three digits

Comment: I guess intercoma can be used only on the forend side inside templates